# lhs2TeX and Syntax conflicting on <> characters

Tags: packages, syntax, grammar, lhs2tex

I'd like to use [Syntax](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/syntax-mdw?lang=en) and [lhs2TeX](https://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/) together, but Syntax's usage of `<>` in production rule names seems to conflict with lhs2TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}

%include lhs2TeX.fmt

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
<foo> ::= <bar>
\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

if I try to typeset this:

```
$ lhs2TeX a.lhs -o a.tex
$ pdflatex a.tex
```

I get

```
! Use of \gr@implitem doesn't match its definition.
l.97 ...n{grammar}\begingroup\par\noindent\advance
                                                  \leftskip\mathindent\(
```

Is there a way to use these two packages together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading `<` characters are interpreted by lhs2TeX as shorthand for the `spec` environment (i.e. literate Haskell that should not be picked up by the compiler), as explained in chapter 3 of its usage guide. I was able to work around this by simply adding a leading space before the `<` on the production rule's left-hand side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}

%include lhs2TeX.fmt

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
 <foo> ::= <bar>
\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

This version is processed by `lhs2TeX` and `pdflatex` as expected.